# Delay when pulling data from API with JS

Tags: javascript, json

I'm pulling a JSON file using js. But since I do this with a for loop, the server gives a 429 error. I looked for ways to slow the cycle. but I couldn't find a working solution.
I tried setTimeOut, I tried delay fetch. I guess it wasn't true.

```
           let koordinatlar = [];
              
           for (let konumOlustur = 0; konumOlustur < 10; konumOlustur++) {
          musteriAdres = encodeURIComponent(yesilListe[0][konumOlustur][5]+' '+yesilListe[0][konumOlustur][6]+' '+yesilListe[0][konumOlustur][7]+' '+yesilListe[0][konumOlustur][8]);
           fetch(`https://api.tomtom.com/search/2/geocode/${musteriAdres}.json?key=APIKEY`)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data)=> 
              koordinatlar.push(
              [data['results'][0]['position']['lon'],
              data['results'][0]['position']['lat'],
              yesilListe[0][konumOlustur][2]+' '+
              yesilListe[0][konumOlustur][3],
              yesilListe[0][konumOlustur][4],
              yesilListe[0][konumOlustur][5]+' '+
              yesilListe[0][konumOlustur][6]+' '+
              yesilListe[0][konumOlustur][7]+' '+
              yesilListe[0][konumOlustur][8]]))
            .catch(function(){
            console.log("hata")
            });
          }
          console.log(koordinatlar);
          </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the page [What are the default QPS limits?](https://developer.tomtom.com/default-qps) on TomTom's website, the default rate limit for the Search API is 5 queries (network requests) per second. This is echoed by [this comment](https://devforum.tomtom.com/t/api-call-made-every-5-seconds-still-gets-429-response/2508/2) and others in the support forums.

You'll need to throttle your requests to **no more than** 5 per second (which translates to 1 query every 200 ms).

You can use a function like this one to create a delay in async code:

```js
function delay (ms) {
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
}
```

and use it with the [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) keyword like this to wait 200ms between requests and avoid the 429 rate limit response from the TomTom API:

```js
function delay (ms) {
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
}

async function fetchGeocodeResult (apiKey, address) {
  const encodedAddress = window.encodeURIComponent(address);
  const url = new URL(`https://api.tomtom.com/search/2/geocode/${encodedAddress}.json`);
  url.searchParams.set('key', apiKey);
  const response = await fetch(url.href);
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Response not OK (Status code: ${response.status})`);
  }
  return response.json();
}

async function example () {
  const apiKey = 'YOUR_ACTUAL_API_KEY';

  const addresses = [
    // An example address from the developer docs:
    'De Ruijterkade 154, 1011 AC, Amsterdam',
    'De Ruijterkade 154, 1011 AC, Amsterdam',
    'De Ruijterkade 154, 1011 AC, Amsterdam',
    'De Ruijterkade 154, 1011 AC, Amsterdam',
    'De Ruijterkade 154, 1011 AC, Amsterdam',
    'De Ruijterkade 154, 1011 AC, Amsterdam',
    // ...etc.
  ];

  for (const address of addresses) {
    const geocodeData = await fetchGeocodeResult(apiKey, address);
    await delay(200);
  }
}
```

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74603529/delay-when-pulling-data-from-api-with-js/74604082?noredirect=1#comment131789426_74604082) @Fuber You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a .setTimeout() for a forced delay.

Check the documentation for the API limit, if there isn’t this information try some different values times until it works.

Comment: I can get it with 500ms or more delay. There is no problem on the server. I also tried the function you mentioned. but this time I didn't get any data.